# Google Reference Error after installing vue-google-autocomplete

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.6

I am using vue.js and Laravel 5.6.12

**[I am following this github page to install vue.js google autocomplete.](https://github.com/olefirenko/vue-google-autocomplete)**

Below is the Step by Step guidelines I followed.

```bash
npm install vue-google-autocomplete --save
```

Then added below code in app.js

```js
import VueGoogleAutocomplete from 'vue-google-autocomplete'
Vue.component('vue-google-autocomplete', VueGoogleAutocomplete);
```

Finally below code in the template.

```html
<vue-google-autocomplete
    id="map"
    classname="form-control"
    placeholder="Start typing">
</vue-google-autocomplete>
```

I got below error

> Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: google is not defined"

[image]

Am I missing anything in above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you have not added google maps script to your `index.html`.

> This component (Vue Google Autocomplete) uses Google Maps Places API to get geo suggests for
>   autocompletion, so **you have to include the Google Maps Places API** in
>   the  of your HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    …
    <!-- NEXT LINE IS SUPER IMPORTANT -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE&libraries=places"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    …
  </body>
</html>
```

If you are using vue cli, you can add it to this file:
https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/develop/template/index.html

BTW: You can find this script on example page as well view-source: https://olefirenko.github.io/vue-google-autocomplete/ (check source code of the page)

**Follow these steps to get an API key**:

- Go to the Google API Console.
- Create or select a project.
- Click Continue to enable the API and any related services.
- On the Credentials page, get an API key. 
  Note: If you have an existing unrestricted API key, or a key with browser restrictions, you may use that key.
- From the dialog displaying the API key, select Restrict key to set a browser restriction on the API key.
- In the Key restriction section, select HTTP referrers (web sites), then follow the on-screen instructions to set referrers.
- (Optional) Enable billing. See Usage Limits for more information.

More info about getting the API key [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)

Comment: I did not add the script url. I will do that. In the above reference page in my question, there is google api console link which sends me here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJwOj.png can u please tell how can i get the api key?

Comment: @Pankaj I've updated the answer, let me know if you have any additional questions

Comment: Can you please give your useful suggestions here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50649177/error-while-implementing-vue2-google-maps-in-vue-js-and-laravel-5-6-12

Comment: @Pankaj ok, answered :)