# Error while implementing vue2-google-maps in vue.js and Laravel 5.6.12

Tags: google-maps-api-3, vue.js, laravel-5.6

I am using Laravel 5.6.12 and vue.js

**[I am implementtrying to implement Google Maps with the help of this github link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps)**

I following the guidelines mentioned in above link as below.

**Installation**

```
npm install vue2-google-maps
```

Then wrote below code in app.js

```
import * as VueGoogleMaps from 'vue2-google-maps'
Vue.component('vue2-google-maps', VueGoogleMaps);
```

**Finally below code in the template**

```
<GmapMap
  :center="{lat:10, lng:10}"
  :zoom="7"
  map-type-id="terrain"
  style="width: 500px; height: 300px"
></GmapMap>
```

I got the below error.

> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive
>   components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

I have already added below script in the html head.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=apikey&libraries=places"></script>
```

Am I missing anything in above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**: You haven't used plugin correctly.

**Long answer**: By default `vue2-google-maps` didn't expose components directly but instead it exposes plugin that *registers* all google maps components (e.g. `<GmapMap/>`). You should read *Quickstart* before using the library.

**> Basic approach - Register plugin**
You should use plugin which will register all the desired components.

Correct usage:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import * as VueGoogleMaps from 'vue2-google-maps'

Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
  load: {
    key: 'YOUR_API_TOKEN',
    libraries: 'places',
})
```

Your usage:

```js
import * as VueGoogleMaps from 'vue2-google-maps'
Vue.component('vue2-google-maps', VueGoogleMaps);
```

BTW: when using this approach you can remove `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/..."></script>` from you `head` with no issue:

**> Alternative approach - Import only required components**. The idea here is to import components directly. I'm not sure how it works with google maps api but in any case you can try

Correct usage:

```js
import GmapMap from 'vue2-google-maps/dist/components/map.vue'
Vue.component('GmapMap', GmapMap)
```

Your usage:

```js
import * as VueGoogleMaps from 'vue2-google-maps'
Vue.component('vue2-google-maps', VueGoogleMaps);
```

Comment: When I try first part which is `Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps`  I get errors **You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.**

Comment: because I already added script in the html head **<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=api&libraries=places"></script>**

Comment: WHen I try second part which is `import GmapMap from 'vue2-google-maps/dist/components/map.vue'
Vue.component('GmapMap', GmapCluster)` I get error **GmapCluster is not defined**

Comment: @Pankaj There was a typo in code. I've just fixed it.

Comment: @Pankaj (to the first comment) You have to remove script from head after switching the libraray because `vue2-google-maps` has build-in  Google Maps JavaScript API

Comment: if I remove the js script, I get previous error which was solved by you here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50647627/google-reference-error-after-installing-vue-google-autocomplete because I have `import VueGoogleAutocomplete from 'vue-google-autocomplete'` for auto complete and import * as VueGoogleMaps from 'vue2-google-maps' for map, Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: @Pankaj It seems like those 2 plugins are not compatible. You can try to use only `vue2-google-maps` as it's already contains autocomplete component (`GmapAutocomplete` ), example here: http://xkjyeah.github.io/vue-google-maps/basic-autocomplete.html

Comment: can u kindly suggest here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50710063/custom-marker-over-google-map