# Custom marker over google map

Tags: google-maps, vue.js, laravel-5.6, vue2-google-maps

**Issue Details**

Default icon is showing and I am expecting a custom icon for marker. Am I missing anything in below code?

I am using Laravel 5.6.12 and vue.js and trying to show custom icon in google map. My code is below in template.

```
<template>
    <div>        
        <gmap-map
            :center="center"
            :zoom="12"
            style="width:100%;  height: 400px;">
            <gmap-marker
              :key="index"
              v-for="(m, index) in markers"
              :position="m.position">
            </gmap-marker>
        </gmap-map>
    </div>
</template>
```

**JS Code**

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return { 
                center: { lat: 30.2457963, lng: 75.84207160000005 },
                markers: [],
                places: []
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.markers.push({ 
                 position: this.center, 
                 icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/parking_lot_maps.png' 
            });
        },
        methods: {

        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You can check https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps/issues/38 for details tutorial

Comment: Can you show the error or result?

Comment: There is no error in the page. I just want to show my icon instead of default red marker.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? Binding icon to the gmap-marker element

```
<gmap-marker
  :key="index"
  v-for="(m, index) in markers"
  :position="m.position">
  :icon="m.icon"   
</gmap-marker>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, and the solution below works. It's as simple as adding `:icon="{ url:'./path-/to/-icon.png'}"` to gmap-marker. For example, your script should look like:

```
<gmap-marker
     :key="index"
     v-for="(m, index) in markers"
     :position="m.position"
     :icon="{ url:'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/parking_lot_maps.png'}">
</gmap-marker>
```

Comment: from where do you get these icon links ? I need an house icon and I can't find one